# how to solve unmet dependencies with libpq5

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, pgadmin

I am trying to install **pgAdmin4** in **ubuntu 18.04**, but I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 10.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 11.2-1.pgdg16.04+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.

**EDIT**

I ran command `apt-cache policy libpq5`, and this is what I got:

```
libpq5:
  Installed: 11.2-1.pgdg16.04+1
  Candidate: 11.2-1.pgdg16.04+1
  Version table:
 *** 11.2-1.pgdg16.04+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     10.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     10.3-1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

But I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: The version 10.6 is the correct version of libpg5 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libpq5) but you've added source(s) that aren't intended for 18.04 (bionic), are unofficial, or you aren't using Ubuntu 18.04 at all (but have 18.04's sources).  A `apt-cache policy libpq5` will show what source you're system is getting 11.2 from and what is creating your issue

Comment: @guiverc I ran the command you said, and I added the result to the body of the question. I am not linux expert user, so I don't know what to do with the result. I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: You installed a version of `libpq5` intended for 16.04; either directly from a `.deb` package or from a repository that you have subsequently removed. You should uninstall that package or upgrade it to a version intended for 18.04.

Answer (score 3):

Install libpq-dev compatible version of libpq5 (10.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 in this case)

`sudo  apt-get install libpq5=10.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`

`sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by manually installing the required dependencies that postgres kindly provide in their repo:

https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/pool/main/p/postgresql-14/

You can just download the matching versions and install using

```bsh
dpkg -i package.deb
```

Comment: How have you found out which ones were needed?

Comment: I would just follow the output of apt when it said which packages were required and then install those ones directly from the Postgres repo